# auto reload: how it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

i need to  change something in my site, if some fields changed in database, but without reloading the page! but i have no idea how i can do it. 
could you give me an idea? thanks

### example:

for example, i have a forum, and i need to show a image, if new comment resieved! i can write all functions, but i don't understand when i must call the function?
maybe window.onload?

Comment: some script intervall code along with ajax

Comment: if i use ajax, for how can i make auto-refreshing???
i can write some functions, but all them will work if i reload the window!

Comment: Same question, asked again and again and again and again. Really, I want to be helpful, but please familiarize yourself with the concept of doing research before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need **AJAX**!

Explanation:

You need two pages, the main page which does not "reload". And a second one which returns two versions of the small image based on the database field.

Page one has this JavaScript in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/* normal ajax without periodical refresh
$.ajax({
  url: 'page2.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#database_status').html(data);
  }
});
*/

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
     $('#database_status').load('/path/to/your.php');
}, 3000);
</script>

// Or you use the jQuery plugin Heartbeat: http://www.jasons-toolbox.com/JHeartbeat/
```

And a div `<div id="database_status">empty</div>`

The second page, returns a image tag based on the database setting for example in PHP:

```
<?php
// do db request 
if ($request) {
    echo '<img src="true.gif"> TRUE';
} else {
    echo '<img src="false.gif"> FALSE';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Once you've familiarized yourself with the concept, you can reference the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for information on how to implement it with jQuery.

Comment: @Matt but how i know, Ajax doesn't solve auto refresh problem, isn't it?

Comment: Ajax means „Asynchronous JavaScript and XML“ this is exactly what you need.

Comment: a litle example will be very useful

Comment: @Syom: You need to load some info from the web server if you want to keep the page up to date. There is no "push" technology that would let you move content into all browsers looking at a certain web page from the server side.

Comment: @Adrian - Well, there are WebSockets ;) @Syom - AJAX is an immensely popular subject. Check out some of the many examples on jQuery's site.. like the [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) page.

Comment: @Matt: True, there are websockets, but that's hardly a technology that I would use in a production system already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuerys load- or JSON-method to get data from your server.

In your case the following scenario is possible:

1. The site loads.
2. Your JavaScript loads the initial data from the server.
3. Now, every couple of seconds or minutes (Depending on your use case), the JavaScript asks the server if anything changed since it last asked (Use timestamps in your request, for example).
4. If so, change the website accordingly.
5. Goto 3.

Please keep in mind that excessive polling might but enormous strains on your server, especially if you have a lot of users. Long-polling or Comet are advanced techniques to handle the load.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to perform an ajax request with jquery is the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. On that page you can also see plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches you can take:

1. Use setInterval to make an Ajax request periodically that ask the server if there are any updates.
2. Use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to fake server push

Answer (score 0):

Try Ajax, e.g: using jquery which allows you to handle those in a high level js. 
[example in this site when you do the send email](http://www.jbasket.com.au)